# Java - Crypt32Util - ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, winapi, encryption, jna

Im trying to decrypt the value of an database on which i have access on.
The password is crypted via Windows API. So my thought was ok. Lets just try then to decrypt it the same way!

Im using Java 1.8.0_60 with JNA-platform.jar...

```
            while (results.next()) {
            String address = results.getString("value1");
            String username = results.getString("value2");
            String password = new String(Crypt32Util.cryptUnprotectData(results.getBytes("value_which_is_crypted")));
            list.add(new String[] { value1,value2,value_which_is_crypted });

        }
```

However, if im trying to execute my code im getting an ClassNotFoundException!

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/jna/Structure
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Crypt32Util.cryptUnprotectData(Crypt32Util.java:121)
at com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Crypt32Util.cryptUnprotectData(Crypt32Util.java:103)
at com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Crypt32Util.cryptUnprotectData(Crypt32Util.java:90)
at recover.Chrome.recover(Chrome.java:35)
at recover.Chrome.main(Chrome.java:49)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.jna.Structure
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
... 17 more
```

I hope this is enough information because this clearly gave me a headache.
Thanks for help!

EDIT:

> ok lesson learned.. when using jna include both jna.jar and jna-platform.jar >in your buildpath! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need `jna.jar` in the classpath - `com/sun/jna/Structure.class` is in that jar.